# How to can i set a margin in a python list to select an item based on its %

Tags: python

I am currently working on the code where i can select a number of items from a certain list. Let's say i have a list:

PD: ['cell-phone:', '76%', '65%', 'bottle:', '89%', '48%', 'person:', '78%', 'mouse:', '44%']

As you can see in total there are 4 objects (cell-phone, bottle, person, mouse), and after objects name you can see a bunch of numbers(%). My task is to somehow sort these numbers so that i will get the nymber with the highest percentage (in our case it will be a bottle since it has 89%) and lastly all objects with a percentage higher than 75% which is going to be a person and a cell-phone from the example above. Here is the code i have been working on which only finds the highest % but without 75% section.

```
PD= ['cell-phone:', '0', '45%', '52%', '53%', '56%', '63%', '61%', '65%', 'bottle:', 
'46%', '62%', '58%', '51%', '50%',
 '48%', 'person:', '47%', 'mouse:', '44%']

# remove colons, percentages, etc
clean_pd = [x.translate({ord(c): None for c in ':%'}) for x in PD]

# convert number strings to integers
convert_to_numbers_pd = [int(x) if x.isnumeric() else x for x in clean_pd]

pd_dict = dict()
pd_key = None

# convert PD data to a dict
for x in convert_to_numbers_pd:
    if isinstance(x, (int,)):
        pd_dict[pd_key].append(x)
    if isinstance(x, (str,)):
        pd_key = x
        pd_dict[pd_key] = list()

# get the max value of each key
for k,v in pd_dict.items():
    print(f"{k}: {max(v)}")
```

Overall, the output should be a list with the following items [bottle, cell-phone, person]
Any help will be appreciated, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to rework your list into a dictionary. Then you can use `max` with a custom key to find the desired item:

```
PD =  ['cell-phone:', '76%', '65%', 'bottle:', '89%', '48%',
       'person:', '78%', 'mouse:', '44%']

# initialize a dictionary
d = {}
for x in PD:              # for each value
    if x.endswith(':'):   # if this is an object
        k = x[:-1]        # get its name
        d.setdefault(k, [])  # ensure we have it as a key
    else:                 # if this is not an object
        d[k].append(int(x.rstrip('%')))  # add the value to the previous object

# get the object with the max value
out = max(d, key=lambda k: max(d[k]))
```

And if you want all keys with values ≥ 75:

```
items_above_75 = [k for k,l in d.items() if any(v>=75 for v in l)]
# ['cell-phone', 'bottle', 'person']
```

*NB. I used the simple assumption that the keys end with `:` and the numbers are either digits `'0'` or digits with a `%` sign `'123%'`. You can of course use any other logic to cleanup the numbers.*

Output: `'bottle'`

Alternative code, that only keep the max value in the loop:

```
d = {}
for x in PD:
    if x.endswith(':'):
        k = x[:-1]
    else:
        val = int(x.rstrip('%'))
        d[k] = max(d.get(k, val), val)

out = max(d, key=d.get)
```

And if you want all keys with values ≥ 75:

```
items_above_75 = [k for k,v in d.items() if v>=75]
# ['cell-phone', 'bottle', 'person']
```

Comment: I just realized you had 2 objectives (max and all items ≥75). I updated the answer to ad the second part

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of items that have any values over 75% in them, you can use this code:

```
PD = ['cell-phone:', '76%', '65%', 'bottle:', '89%', '48%', 'person:', '78%', 'mouse:', '44%']
PD = [x.replace("%", "") for x in PD]
PD_dict = {}
for x in PD:
    try:
        x = int(x)
        PD_dict[current_key].append(x)
    except ValueError:
        current_key = x
        PD_dict[x] = []
result = []
for x in PD_dict:
    if max(PD_dict[x]) > 75:
        result.append(x.replace(":",""))
result
```

Output: `['cell-phone', 'bottle', 'person']`